# Deselect items from select all

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools

How would I deselect an item from the A keyboard shortcut to select all? Like if I wanted to deselect the plane (pic below)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this answers your question. To make an Object unselectable, you just have to toggle it in your Scene Collection. If you're asking how to deselect an object in general it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M1</kbd>

[image: select]

Comment: thanks that works, but a shortcut or something would be even more helpful, like maybe right-click to deselect?

Comment: Shift + left-click in the viewport is deselecting the object again. CTRL + left-click in your Scene collection will deselect the object too.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!